# add a new column named Natco to the merged excel file using r

Tags: r, excel, merge, rbind

I'm trying to merge multiple excel files into one using this code:

```
df <- rbind(df1, df2, df3, df4, df5)
```

This code is running correctly and gave me the right output. But i need to add new column (Natco) at the end of merge dataframe which could add the name of each dataframe from where this file is coming Something like;

```
col1      col2   col3    col4    col5    Natco
5200      2018   text    short   term    df1
5300      2014   text    short   term    df2
5400      2017   string  short   term    df3
...       ...     ...     ...     ...    ...
```

Anyone know how to do it in R?

Ahsan

Comment: which package you use to import excel files to R?

Comment: you should add a column `Natco` with the name of the dataframe right before `merging`. That way the end result will contain one column with the correct Natco info.

Comment: @Mislav, I', using readxl package to load excel file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could cbind a "Natco" column to every df priot to rbind.

Implementation would look something like:

`df1 <- cbind(df1, "Natco"="df1")
df2 <- cbind(df2, "Natco"="df2")`

and then

`df <- rbind(df1, ... , df2)`

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
library(readxl)

excel_files <- list.files("fullPathToFolderWhereExcelFilesSits", full.names = TRUE)
df <- lapply(excel_files, read_xlsx, sheet = 1L)
for(i in 1:length(excel_files)){
  df[[i]]["Natco"] <- gsub(".*/", "", excel_files[i])
}
```

Comment: doesnot work for me. This code throws me an error "Error in `*tmp*`[[i]] : subscript out of bounds". What type of issue it is?

Comment: I tried and it works for me. After which line you get an error?